# Not detecting relations between classes using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 classes. Links and Info need to be connected. The Info class has a Link_id and the Link has a User_id.

I want users to see the info of their links in their personal dashboards. So a User, has many links, one Link has many Info.

Link model has:

```
    public function infos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('info');

    }
}
```

Info model has:

```
    public function link()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('link');
    }
```

The dashboard has a controller.
I managed to get all links by searching for a user_id

```
$linksByOwner = Link::where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
```

Now i'm trying to reach the info that's nestled in the Link. I tried this using:

```
    $collectedData = $linksByOwner->infos(); < Not working
    $collectedData = Info::where('link_id',19)->info(); < Not working

    dd($collectedData);
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::infos does not exist.
```

Some extra info:
both models have a foreign key connected to them in the database migration

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
```

```
 $table->foreign('link_id')
                ->references('id')->on('links')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Could someone show or tell me how I could fix this? Is it a scoping error? Do I need to connect the classes differently?

Comment: Whats the correct name of the „info“ and the „link“ table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `pluck` the `infos` from the Collection of Links you have (assuming the relationships are setup correctly):

```
$linksByOwner = Link::with('infos')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

$infos = $linksByOwner->pluck('infos');
```

Comment: This pluck returns an array. Is it possible to make it return an object?

Comment: `pluck` returns a new Collection (object), not an array

Answer (score 0):

`$linksByOwner` is a `Collection` of `Link` models; you can't access a relationship (`infos`) unless you loop over each one.

```
$linksByOwner = Link::with(['infos'])->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
foreach($linksByOwner AS $linkByOwner){
  $collectedData = $linkByOwner->infos; // Don't need the `()` here
  dd($collectedData); // Should be a `Collection` of `Info` models
}
```

Also note, `return $this->belongsTo('link');` and `return $this->hasMany('info');` `link` and `info` should be either `'App\Link'`/`'App\Info'`, `App\Link::class`/`App\Info::class` or, if you're importing `Link` and `Info` via `use App\Link;` and `use App\Info;`, then `'Link'`/`'Info'` or `Link::class`/`Info::class`.

I'm unsure if `'link'` and `'info'` would properly reference your model:

```
public function infos(){
  return $this->hasMany(App\Info::class);
}

public function link(){
  return $this->belongsTo(App\Link::class);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try modifying Eloquent relationship, indicating that it is a class.

```
public function links(){
   return $this->hasMany(Link::class);
}
```

Comment: Hello! I changed the Links and Info class like you said and it gives the same error:    public function links()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Link::class);
    }